# Handling errors in python

Tags: python, file-io, error-handling

I'm writing a small parser class for a personal project. The class will essentially parse popular playlist files and return useful information.

Since the class will interact with files, I'm not sure about the best way to handle errors. I'm a Linux guy and generally do things in errno fashion but I'm wondering that whether exceptions are a better selection or not.

In short what's the best way to handle these things in python world?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `with` and exceptions..

Comment: There are some file i/o related examples in the python docs on [handling exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html#d0e14928) from Dive Into Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use exceptions. And if you are using python 2.7, you want to use the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

There is a [good tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) in the standard python documentation , but there are tons of other recources: [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions), [dive into python](http://ccn.ucla.edu/tutorials/diveintopython/file_handling/index.html), [articles in blogs](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/how-tos/python-exception-handling/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question pretty much.